# Difference between Genymotion and ADB

Tags: android, genymotion

Genymotion has virtual device management and also the ADB tool.

Both are required to run atleast 1 device for running Android app.

The basics are identical. How do the both tools differ ?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 4):

Genymotion is more effective and fast rather than default avd.Genymotion is now fastest avd in the market right now give you opengl and x86 architecture virtualization control are quite easy and most of all user friendly.

i also use genymotion for testing apps

Comment: Thanks for reply. For a build system Genymotion also needs to be running in the memory. So how to automate then the android unit test.

Comment: Genymotion VMs are considered as physical devices, so any unit test tool compatible with Android devices can be used.

Comment: I tried the Genymotion, its configured device needs to be running.Cant we run the Android unit tests like Java Junit tests which run independently ?

Comment: Everything you need is here : http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html