# Android AVD is not launching

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

i want to start Android application development but my avd is taking forever to launch and sometime it show me error that your device is not responding close or wait.what to do???
i have i3 laptop with 4 gb ram so i don't think so my laptop configuration is low for it.
i have tried waiting for nearly half an hour and still got no result.
i have already try to follow tutorials and still it all end in to zero.
thanks for your time.
can any one suggest best configuration for avd so can start it up and running.

Comment: provide the current conf of your AVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start AVD with minimum screen resolution and check if that works. Sometimes loading AVD with high resolution emulator does not work. I had the same problem and  i opened emulator using small screen resolution and boom it worked. :)
Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple configuration so you can be sure it isnt about resources of your machine. Use a ARM CPU, 3.2 QVGA device, 100mb internal and 256 ram. I have a laptop configuration close to what you describe, and it takes with eclipse on about 8 minutes to start the avd. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with AVD, I'd highly encourage to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem , and i fixed it by change CPU/ABI to ARM in emulator configuration

Answer (score 0):

Leave Default AVD and Use GenyMotion Download Link below
https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc

and refer to my answer why genymotion is better than default avd
[Difference between Genymotion and ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903105/difference-between-genymotion-and-adb/21904122#21904122)